# Is "see the forest for the trees" an appropriate expression for my situation?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, phrases, idioms

I am not an academic, but for some reason, I am now a struggling writer, not for lack of nourishment, food or inspiration, but language skills.
I am documenting a very early collection of photographs, pre 1920, all cataloged with the accompanying index, identifications and information.
In good keeping with historical documentation, I try to search every lead, thread, link and comment about the individual images, their creators, and their ultimate fates.

After over two years of continuous work, out of the blue a few days ago it became apparent to me that what I was missing was the fact that this collection was more than just details, links, and facts related to some photographs. What I was looking at was a singular mass, a unit, a (compendium?), a being, a forest which I was trying to deal with one tree, one branch, one leaf, at a time.

The use of the above reference (to trees and forests) is usually related to people in an abstract way, from my reading. Is it appropriate to use such a reference to the collections of things, or is this a misuse of the phrase?

P.S. already started searching 'Compendium', very interesting, and possible answer. Any suggested reading?

Comment: You need to start developing a *narrative,* the larger story that the collection of photographs will help you tell. Write for your readers. What would *you* like to read about the pictures and their stories?

Comment: Perhaps a different title would help, e.g., "What is the best word or phrase for a collection of historical photographs with accompanying notes about the photographer, subject, time period, etc.?"

Comment: I forgot to say that I think it's a great question that will help others in the future. +1. :0)

Answer (score 2):

You are "documenting a very early collection of photographs".  Your term, collection, is right on target--that's what an archivist would call such a collection, although it might also be called an archive (singular).

Archivists usually do what you are doing--detailed cataloging and documenting.  Usually considered especially important is the source of the material--how it got put together--and its provenance (who owned it when) to verify authenticity.

Archivists usually summarize the scope of collections, but leave interpretation to users (historians, academics, etc.).

A recent reference is *From Polders to Postmodernism: A Concise History of Archival Theory*, by John Ridener (Litwin Books, 2009). (And that really is Polders, with a P.)

If you are going to write an article about this collection, you would want to develop a narrative about it, as @Mark Hubbard suggests.

@sumelic has reminded me that I didn't directly address your question about the appropriateness of the phrase "not seeing the forest for the trees."  It is apt--the individual items of the collection are the trees, and the collection is the forest.  The phrase usually refers to a *person* who has gotten so involved in details that he or she has lost sight of the big picture (the forest) and needs to step back and look at the whole, the entirety, the pattern.

dictionary.com [can't see the forest for the trees](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22can%27t%20see%20the%20forest%20for%20the%20trees%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) gives this definition and example:

> An expression used of someone who is too involved in the details of a
>   problem to look at the situation as a whole: “The congressman became
>   so involved in the wording of his bill that he couldn't see the forest
>   for the trees; he did not realize that the bill could never pass.”

Comment: You might also search the Internet for "photographic archives" for examples and commentary.

Comment: I feel like this, while likely to help the original poster, doesn't answer the actual question posed. I did edit the title, so that part's not from the original post and might be wrong, but the text of the question does say "The use of the above reference (to trees and forests) is usually related to people in an abstract way, from my reading. **Is it appropriate to use such a reference to the collections of things, or is this a misuse of the phrase?**" It seems to me the question is about the use of the phrase "see the forest for the trees", not about how to describe what archivists do.

Comment: I thought he was asking about the term "compendium" and possible alternatives.  And he asks for a reference.

Comment: Ah, I see! Yes, now I notice that the original post also asks about the suitability of the word "compendium".

Comment: @sumelic I see what you mean, too, so I added something about the phrase in the answer.